# How to highlight country when hovered over in LeafletJS?

Tags: leaflet

I got
the quick start guide loaded up here...

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('API KEY', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(mymap);
```

How would I go about coding this when I want the country border to be highlighted when it is hovered over? Do I need a .js file that contains the list/dictionary for all these polygons?

Anything helps.
Thanks

Comment: Yes you have to load all countries into your map. Take a look here: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: @FalkeDesign I saw the .js file for all the states. Is there a .js file for all countries anywhere?